# Механизмы поиска документов (контента) сайта

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, полнотекстовый-поиск, lucene

Надо определиться с подходом организации поиска по сайту. В связи с этим сей вопрос. Он может показаться несколько общим, но тем не менее.

Пару тройку лет назад реализовывали проект на `Orchard CMS` (.net mvc). Дак вот фреймворк использовал `Lucene.Net` для полнотекстового поиска материалов сайта. С точки зрения разработчика подключение индексации было весьма простым, и имело примерно такой вид:

```
OnIndexing<EduPart>((ctx, ep) => ctx.DocumentIndex
    .Add("EduPart_Description", ep.Description).RemoveTags().Analyze()
    .Add("EduPart_Mission", ep.Mission).RemoveTags().Analyze()
);
```

Индекс хранится, я уже и не помню где, либо в базе либо в файлах. Но суть в том, что никаких внешних обращений и зависимостей данный поиск не имел.

Реализуемые проекты достаточно невелики, задачи индексировать википедию не стоит. Основной используемый фреймворк - `CakePHP`, но это не важно, все популярные mvc фреймворки нынче так или иначе реализуют одни и те же вещи.

Какие видятся возможности для поиска и их применимость:

- банальное использование `LIKE` оператора. самый простой и самый менее функциональный вариант для поиска контента. Да можно искать по заголовкам, например, но до полнотекстового тут далеко. Как решение не рассматривается.
- Использование инструментов Full text search движков БД. Проблемой (хоть и решаемой) тут является использование различных СУБД. В принципе я в разработке применяю только MS SQL Server и MySQL, оба этих ядра поддерживают полнотекстовые индексы, хотя честно признаюсь,  ни разу не пользовался. В общем, тут придется писать реализации поиска под каждую СУБД.
- использование поисковых машин типа elasticSearch/sphinx/solr и т.п. В таких подходах это отдельные сервисы/демоны обращение, к которым идет через API. Минусы - возможности переноса проектов на хостинги могут быть ограничены. Сам CakePHP имеет [плагин для ElasticSearch](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/elasticsearch.html), как ни странно, требующий при этом изменения иерархии наследования моделей/сущностей приложения, хотя казалось бы, требуется-то реализация некоего поведения, реагирующего на события добавления/редактирования/удаления контента.
- Последним вариантом (на который на который я изначально расчитывал) был порт Lucene на PHP. Раньше таковой был частью `Zend Framework`, и назывался `Zend.Search`. Однако беда в том, что данный проект [не совместим с пхп 7](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSearch/issues/24) и более не поддерживается. Как написано последняя версия пхп для него 5.3.

Вот из этих размышлений вытекает и задача - найти решение для полнотекстового поиска на сайте (по всем типам документов/контента) без использования сторонних поисковых машин и не зависящее от используемого диалекта SQL.

Кто может поделиться опытом по сему вопросу? Какие есть еще варианты решения данной задачи, или библиотеки подходящие под условия.

Comment: нашелся какой-то [Pucene](https://github.com/pucene), пока не ясно.

Answer (score 0):

В общем остановился на полнотекстовом поиске средствами СУБД. Посмотрел, что на нескольких обычных хостингах разрешены полнотекстовые индексы, хотя сомневался в этом, поскольку, например, триггеры и представления часто запрещены.

С точки зрения реализации на стороне СУБД, пошел таким путем, что фактически создается вспомогательная таблица для поиска. В таблице два поля - id документа и его контент. Контент конкатенируется из полей самого документа. Фактически получается дублирование контента в БД, но поскольку его не много, то не критично.

С точки зрения приложения (CakePHP), разработал `SearchBehavior`, который подключается к таблицам. Примерно так:

```
    $this->addBehavior("Search", [
        'className' => 'ContentManager.Search',
        'indexFields' => [
            'title', 'description',
            'Specs.title', 'Edu.title'
        ],
        'results' => [
            'select' => ['notice'],
            'contains' => ['Specs'],
            'url' => ['_name' => 'profDetails'],
        ]
    ]);
```

в конфиге указывается перечень конкатенируемых полей, в т.ч. ассоциаций. Для отображения результатов поиска возможно указание выбираемых полей (в дополнение к `displayField()` по умолчанию), а также загружаемых ассоциаций. Для построения ссылки в результатах на конкретный документ используются либо именованные маршруты (куда передается `id` как параметр), либо callback-метод.

Стандартную пагинацию пришлось конфигурировать вручную. Параметры находятся в `$this->params('paging')` контроллера.

Документы индексируются/удаляются из индекса в событиях `afterSave` и `afterDelete`. Также разработан шелл, позволяющий очищать поисковую таблицу, индексировать документы по типу, или все сразу.
На уровне поведения/таблиц добавлен (добалвены на уровне поведения, перекрывается на уровне конечных `Table`-классов при необходимости) метод `allowIndex($entity)` позволяющий определять, следует ли индексировать конкретный документ. Таким образом можно индексировать не все документы заданного типа, а только часть из них.

Остался нюанс, когда одна таблица БД используется под несколько  классов моделей. Но такая ситуация у меня имеет место быть только для элементов меню сайта. Так что пока что индексируются только элементы одного из них.